# Xcodeでpythonを使う方法

Tags: python3, xcode

Xcodeでpython3を使う方法を教えてください。
いろいろなサイトを見たのですが、どれも古い情報なのでうまくいかなかったです。
ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

この記事が参考になると思います

[開発環境】XcodeでPython【画面遷移あり】](https://qiita.com/Cremokoroah/items/1fe8396de291a8c12d08)

最新の環境での変更点は、手続き3-3, 3-4で`python`ではなく`python3`を選択する必要があります。

しかし、無理矢理`Xcode`で`Python`を使ってもあまり良いことは無く、`VSCode`や`PyCharm`を使った方が良いと思います。

Comment: VScodeでもApp Storeに配信するアプリ（IOS,macOS向け）を作れるのでしょうか？（Xcodeでpythonをやろうとしていたのは、App Storeに配信する用のアプリ（ゲームなど）を作りたかったからです。（説明が足りていなくてすみません））

Comment: `Python`でApp Storeに配信するアプリを作れるという話を寡聞にして聞いたことがありません

Comment: やはり無理やりpythonを使うのではなくSwiftなどを使った方が良いのでしょうか

Comment: はい。iOSには`Python`はインストールされていないでしょうし、実行ファイルはIntelとarmのユニバーサルバイナリーである必要があります（masOS)少なくとも、Pythonでもarmバイナリーにコンパイルされる必要があると思います